# Issue highlighting selected li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change the background color of the li element selected but my code is not working as expected, it changes the background color but just for one second, I want it to keep the background color changed while it is still the selected element, this is my code

```
 $('#campoBuscarProducto').keydown(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode === 40) {

        ++contador;

        if (contador >= resultado) { contador = 0; }

        if (contador <= resultado - 1) {

            $('#listaDeProductos > li').removeClass('cambiandoProducto');      
            $('#listaDeProductos > li').eq(contador).addClass('cambiandoProducto');
        }
    }

    if (e.keyCode === 38) {

        --contador;

        if (contador < 0) { contador = resultado - 1; }

        if (contador >= 0) {

            $('#listaDeProductos > li').removeClass('cambiandoProducto');      
            $('#listaDeProductos > li').eq(contador).addClass('cambiandoProducto');
        }
    }
}); //Missing close parenthesis :-)
```

This is my CSS class:

```
.cambiandoProducto {

    background-color: red;
}
```

Do you have an idea about what I'm missing or what is the issue with my code? maybe something related to the `keydown` event?, thanks.

The `ul` list is generated after `success` function with this code

```
$.each(datos, function(i) {

    opciones += '<li class="sugerencias">' + datos[i].nombre + '</li>';
});

resultado = datos.length;

$('#coincidenciasBusqueda').show();
$('#coincidenciasBusqueda').html('<ul id="listaDeProductos">'+ opciones +'</ul>');
```

Comment: Do you have an errors in your console? Also have you tried putting `!important` in your CSS?

Comment: please share html code as well

Comment: Please have a read of this: [mcve].  Especially the verifiable part - there doesn't appear to be any obviously wrong with your code, so there may be something else causing the issue - especially if it says red for "just for one second".

Comment: There aren't errors, and yes, I tried adding `!important` to the CSS but it still changes the background color just for one second

Comment: Please could you provide the relevant html?

Comment: I think it would help for a lot of people to have the varnames in english (or at least a description of what they mean)

For example, I don't know what 'contador' is...

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar I updated the info

Comment: As you confirm, there aren't any errors and your code is not causing the issue, so there must be some other code in your project/site/page causing it.   Hence the verifiable part of that link.  Try creating a jsfiddle.net version and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.

Comment: As an aside, your code would really benefit from the DRY principle.

Comment: I've mocked up the example you have in jsfiddle according to what I understand from your question. If this is working as expected, you should be able to port the implementation over to your existing implementation. https://jsfiddle.net/3y84hbba/

Comment: @JacobHeater yes, it should work as you did, but it still is not working for me still is changing the color just for one second, I have no more javascript files before my code, just `jquery` and `bootstrap.min.js` and with my css file there are two files before `font-awesome` and `bootstrap`

Comment: @ProfessorZoom When are you adding the keydown listener? Are you adding it before the elements are added to the page? Are you adding it on  document ready? There are a lot of questions that your post does not answer. We need the full picture to be able to assist.

Comment: @JacobHeater I'm adding the listener when I write something in the input `#campoBuscarProducto` but to get the value of element running the ajax request I'm using the `keyup` event in the same input which is the searcher, could it be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue, the problem was that I was using `keydown` listener to run the code to change the background color of the selected `li` element but before to run my ajax call I was using `keyup` event listener, these listener were associated to the same `input` but in different functions so this was generating the issue.

I **solved** this changing the `keyup` event listener with `keypress` and it is working very well right now, thank you all guys for your help.

It was my mistake and I apologize to do not explain better how I was running my ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var contador = $('ul li').length, resultado = 1;
$('li').eq(resultado - 1).addClass('color');
$('ul').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    resultado++;
    if (resultado > contador) 
      resultado = 1;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    resultado--;
    if (resultado <= 0)
      resultado = contador;
  }
  $('li').removeClass('color');
  $('li').eq(resultado - 1).addClass('color');
  //console.log('selected item: ' + resultado);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.color {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
click on "ul" to focus
<br>
<ul tabindex="0" >
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to simplify your index test:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="campoBuscarProducto" />
<ul id="listaDeProductos">
  <li class="sugerencias">asd</li>
  <li class="sugerencias">ygjhgh</li>
  <li class="sugerencias">ret</li>
  <li class="sugerencias">87687</li>
  <li class="sugerencias">-0-</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var contador = 0;
var resultado = 5;
$('#campoBuscarProducto').keydown(function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        contador++;
        console.warn(contador);
        if (contador > resultado) { 
          contador = 1;
        }
        $('#listaDeProductos > li').removeClass('cambiandoProducto');      
        $('#listaDeProductos > li').eq(contador - 1).addClass('cambiandoProducto');

    }

    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        contador--;
        console.warn(contador);
        if (contador == 0) { contador = resultado; }
        $('#listaDeProductos > li').removeClass('cambiandoProducto');      
        $('#listaDeProductos > li').eq(contador - 1).addClass('cambiandoProducto');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.cambiandoProducto {

    background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/diego_carrascal/no2p0jzo/)